# Android : JSON Parser with async task (GET and POST methods)

Tags: java, android

Just want to check whether this JSON Parser with async task is it correctly done? When I put this code into my Eclipse, this (method.equals("POST") was underline red. And it state that the 'method' cannot be solved. Any suggestion or help in this? Thank you.

```
public class JSONParser {

  static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";
  String url=null;
     List<NameValuePair> nvp=null;
     // constructor
     public JSONParser() {

   }

  // function get json from url
  // by making HTTP POST or GET method
   public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
      BackGroundTask Task= new BackGroundTask(url, method,  params);
    try {
        return Task.execute().get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
public class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{
    List<NameValuePair> postparams= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String URL=null;
public BackGroundTask(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        URL=url;
        postparams=params;
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
    // Making HTTP request 
        // check for request method

    if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postparams));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(postparams, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You forgot to declare `method` property in your BackGroundTask class.

**EDIT** Like this:

```
public class BackGroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{
    List<NameValuePair> postparams= new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String URL=null;
    String method = null;
public BackGroundTask(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
        URL=url;
        postparams=params;
        this.method = method;
    }
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
    // Making HTTP request 
        // check for request method

    if(method.equals("POST")){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postparams));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(postparams, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

   }
 }
}
```

Comment: `public BackGroundTask(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
   URL=url;
   postparams=params;
                        method=method; < like this?
  }`

Comment: Yup, and declare it in your class body.

Comment: Optionally you can pass this parameter to execute() method.

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry, you had to make your answer when I was writing mine.

Comment: Need some help again.. But my codes are kind of long.. How? :'(

Comment: Will the postparams affect the other part of the activity codes ?

Comment: You have your class `BackGroundTask`, wich is a representation of the task. When you create new object using `new`, you pass parameters to this. You do this in constructor. Then you call execute which runs your code once. After that, your object is destroyed.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to implement this with the `header` parameter? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set method as a class variable within BackGroundTask. You are passing it into the constructor but not going anything with it. Set it the same way you have done with url and postparams.

Comment: Where to set it or where to set the method as a class variable within backgroundtask? I am a little confused.